# Integration of $r J_0(r)$

Tags: laplace-transform, bessel-functions

**Question**

Let $J_0(r)$ denote the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero, I'd like to compute the following integration:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} rJ_0(r) dr $$

I tried using the Laplace transformation to compute this but I'm not sure if I'm doing right. Is my approach correct? Do you have any other approches to prove this?

**My attempt**

Using the differential property of Laplace transform, we have
$$\mathcal{L}\{tf(t)\} = \int_0^\infty tf(t) e^{-st} dt = -\frac{d \mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}}{ds} $$
Based on the [Proof Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laplace_Transform_of_Bessel_Function_of_the_First_Kind_of_Order_Zero), the Laplace transform of the Bessel function is:
$$\mathcal{L}\{J_0(t)\}  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}$$
Therefore, it follows that
$$\mathcal{L}\{rJ_0(r)\} =\frac{d}{ds}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}\right) = \frac{s}{(s^2+1)^{3/2}} $$
In other words, we have
$$\int_0^\infty rJ_0(r) e^{-sr} dr = \frac{s}{(s^2+1)^{3/2}} $$
Thus, by considering the limit: $s \rightarrow 0$, we obtain the following:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} rJ_0(r) dr = 0 $$

Comment: The result is correct, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E43 more generally. You have to justify, the interchange in the limit and integration though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Gary. My bad. Since I'm an engineering student, I often interchange the limit and integration without deep thought.

Comment: @Gary, actually the result doesn't hold for the exponent that is being considered, and it's evidently outside the region of convergence of the formula you quote. The integral is clearly divergent and can only be assigned a value through some sort of analytic continuation...

Comment: @DinosaurEgg My bad, I focused on the first condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other users noted, your integral is *indeterminate* but at the limit of some transformation (Laplace, Mellin) is zero:

This is more clear with the Mellin transform. Consider the series expansion of $J_{0}$:

$\displaystyle J_{0}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2/4)^{j}}{j!^2}$

then

$\displaystyle I= \int_{0}^{\infty} x J_{0}(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} x\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2/4)^{j}}{j!^2} dx$

Let $\displaystyle w = x^2 \Longrightarrow dw=2xdx$

then
$\displaystyle I =  \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-w/4)^{j}}{j!^2} dw$

Now, denote $\displaystyle f(w) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-w/4)^{j}}{j!^2} dx $

and consider the Mellin transform of the $f(w)$ function:

$\displaystyle \left\{ \mathscr{M} f \right\}(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}w^{s-1} f(w) dw =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}w^{s-1} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-w/4)^{j}}{j!^2} dw $

your integral is the Mellin transform at $s=1$

By Ramanujan's master theorem:

If we denote $\displaystyle \phi(j)= \frac{1}{4^j\Gamma(j+1)}$

therefore

$\displaystyle \left\{\mathscr{M} f \right\}(s)  =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}w^{s-1} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-w/4)^{j}}{j!^2} dw = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma(s)\phi(-s) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{4^s\Gamma(s)}{\Gamma(1-s)} $

If we put $\displaystyle s=1$ clearly the right hand side is  *indeterminate*

But if we take the limit as $\displaystyle s \to 1$

$\displaystyle \lim _{s\to 1} \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}w^{s-1} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-w/4)^{j}}{j!^2} dw = \lim_{s\to 1} \frac{1}{2}\frac{4^s\Gamma(s)}{\Gamma(1-s)} = 0 $

The conclusion is that the integral is zero only if we express it as a limit of the transformation (you cannot interchange the limit and integral operation)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int{xJ_0\left( x \right) dx}
\\
=xJ_1\left( x \right) 
\\
\int_0^{\infty}{xJ_0\left( x \right) dx}
\\
=xJ_1\left( x \right) |_{0}^{\infty}
$$
But we know
$$
J_{\alpha}\left( x \right) \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos \left( x-\frac{\alpha \pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4} \right) 
$$
and
$$
J_1(0)=0
$$
We can conclude from these two facts that the integral is divergent

Comment: 1) Take care : $J_{\alpha}\left( x \right) \color{red}{\approx}...$ not $J_{\alpha}\left( x \right) \color{red}{=}...$ 2) The fact that a software says an integral is divergent does not deserve a screen copy : we believe you ; moreover, as it is written in chinese, consider that 85% of mankind isn't able to read it.

Comment: Thank you for reminding！